# How to use multible routes in MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a website that need a departmentID for all sites, so i rewrote the default route to the following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Main",
            url: "{deptID}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", deptID = "", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

It works fine when you for example use the following URL:

http://domain/2/Home/Index

or just simply:

http://domain/2

My problem is that when i go to "http://domain/" i get an error because i dont have specified the departmentID.
How can i add a second route which will fire when you just go to the domain.

I have tried to add the following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Start",
            url: "/",
            defaults: new { controller = "Department", action = "Select"}
        );
```

Which doesnt work since you cant just put "/" as an URL.

I have also tried to add the default route and then just change the defaults object:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Department", action = "Select", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

This doesnt work either.

Comment: What error you get in the first place? Since you provided a default value for `deptID` in the `defaults`, you should hit your controller action with no error. Post your controller and the error then.

Comment: this link solved your problem: [Multiple Routes in MVC asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139743/registering-multiple-routes-in-mvc-asp-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have to modify your code as below**

```
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Department",
          url: "{deptID}/{controller}/{action}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Department", action = "Index"}
      );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );


    }
```

**Output**

[image: Home URL]
[image: Department URL with ID]

Let me know if the above code still not worked for you.

Comment: It doesnt give me an error now, but it calls the HomeController rather than the DepartmentController which i have set in the defaults object.

Comment: It works. But it looks like i dont even need two routes. I can just use the main route and then make sure the default action doesnt require a departmentID parameter.